# CSS - Display items in columns

Tags: html, css

I have a code like this

```css
.list {
  height: 592px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 164px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 7</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 9</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>Block 10</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want display like this

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCQNI.png)

But do not use flex, column count, position absolute.
When items go to max width, it auto break to new line (under Social networks like image)

Is there any help. Thanks so much

Comment: Can you add the image?

Comment: @DevAnanth Yes, I've added like image

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your elements "flow" downwards and to the right, you need to apply to the parent element:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;  /* To make children "flow" downwards */
flex-wrap: wrap;         /* To make overflow children "flow" to the right */
```

Here is an example, in which I just replaced the repetitive HTML with a JavaScript code to generate children elements with random heights:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('list');

parent.innerHTML = [...Array(10).keys()].reduce(
  (acc, index) => {
    const randomHeight = Math.random() * 100 + 30;
    return `${acc}<div class="item" style="height: ${randomHeight}px"><span>Block ${index}</span></div>`
  },
  '',
);
```

```css
#list {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;

  /* This is where the magic happens */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 164px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: Ya. I also used flex-direction: column. but when has many item, it appeear scroll horizontal. number of item is flexible, but width of each item is fixed and must magin-right each other 20px

Comment: Try increasing the amount of elements in my code - it still overflows to the right (not to the bottom)

Comment: ya. i use flex column and it appear scroll horizontal. but i want vertical